# Border of the button with the icon

Tags: c++, qt

In the constructor, I set the style for the form and buttons:

```
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    this->setStyleSheet("QWidget {background: rgb(49, 54, 59); color: rgb(220, 221, 218); selection-color: lightyellow; selection-background-color: darkcyan;}"
                        "QPushButton::hover {color: darkcyan; border: 2px solid grey; border-radius: 3px};");
}
```

Next, in the properties (`icon` parameter) of the button, I added an `icon` via resources, I also set the icon size using the `iconSize` parameter - `20x20`, I also set the `flat` - `True` parameter in.

And this is what I get when I hover the cursor over the button:

[image]

The size of the button itself is formed using the layout and the `size` is `32x26`, when the picture is set to `20x20`.

Please tell me how you can remove this `gap` between the `picture` and the `border` of the button?

I tried to set the button size statically, about `22x22` and then everything is more or less fine, but I don't want to resort to such a radical solution. Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could separate styling for the button as `myButton->setStyleSheet("ButtonStyle")`?

Comment: @AlexanderV, I think it has nothing to do with it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to [Qt's box model](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-customizing.html#box-model), the gap between the border and the icon is the [padding](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/stylesheet-reference.html#padding-prop).

In the stylesheet, you can set the padding to 0 as followed `padding: 0px;`

Comment: It's a good idea, but it still doesn't look very good, there is a certain deviation in width. Maybe there is a parameter that would stretch the icon over the entire area of the button?

Comment: There could have been a button minimum width set. You should update the question to give a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: However, you are right, your answer answers my question.